# C# gRPC Unhandled Exception on BlockingUnaryCall call

Tags: c#

I have a .NET gRPC server / client application. It did already works. But now I get on all server calls the follow error in the grpc client:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Cancelled, Detail="Cancelled")
 bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 bei Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Internal\AsyncCall.cs:Zeile 78.
 bei Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\DefaultCallInvoker.cs:Zeile 46.
 bei Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext2 ctx) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Interceptors\InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:Zeile 51.
 bei Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation2 continuation) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\ClientBase.cs:Zeile 174.  
 bei Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) in T:\src\github\grpc\src\csharp\Grpc.Core\Interceptors\InterceptingCallInvoker.cs:Zeile 48.
```

I undone everything. The error remains. I just don`t know the cause.

I am using .NET 4.7.2, Grpc 1.21.0 and Google.Protobuf 3.8.0.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Check the last request you sent and the response.  Look at the response status (like 200 OK) to determine the cause of the issue.  The messages are http which uses TCP as the transport layer.  Make sure the TCP connection is not closing [FIN].

Comment: Thanks for your support. The TCP connection works. But I saw in the frpc server output window from VisualStudio the message "Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll". This message is shown everytime when i send a repsonse from the client.

Comment: A file is trying to be opened on the server using the library System.IO.  The default folder that is used in opening the file is the same folder where the c# executable is located.  The exception posted gives no detail about this exception.  You may need to add a path to the file name if the file is not in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: Now I get the solution. There was missing the System.Interactive.Async.dll reference on server side.

Thanks for your support.